# How can I get HighCharts column chart to scale the yAxis to not have so much whitespace?

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart that I'm working at at [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelWitt/a23j4Ljd/1/).  In it, I have a min set to 81 and max set to 105 on the yAxis so that the chart will take up the full height.  However, as soon as I give a max over 100, it rounds it up to 120 so my chart shrinks down.  If the max is changed to 100, then it shows it the way I want to see it (although some of the bar is cut off).  Any idea how to get this chart to scale so that the yAxis area is just a little bigger than my bars?  Code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    "chart": {
        "type": "column",
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "spacing": [10, 10, 10, 10],
        "height": 100
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "title": {
        "text": ""
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "crosshair": true,
        "labels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "style": {
                "font": "Arial",
                "fontSize": "10px",
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                "zIndex": -100
            },
            "useHTML": true
        },
        "tickWidth": 0,
        "tickLength": 0,
        "type": "category"
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "min": 81,
        "max": 100,
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "gridLineWidth": 0,
        "minorGridLineWidth": 0,
        "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "labels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "format": "{value}%"
        },
        "title": {
            "text": ""
        },
        "plotBands": [{
            "color": "#f1c40f",
            "from": 94.7,
            "to": 95.3,
            "label": null
        }, {
            "color": "#2ecc71",
            "from": 99.5,
            "to": 100.5,
            "label": null
        }]
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "pointPadding": 0.2,
            "borderWidth": 0
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "enabled": true,
        "shared": true,
        "useHTML": true
    },
    "series": [{
        "data": [{
            "name": "M",
            "y": 103,
            "color": "#2ecc71"
        }, {
            "name": "A",
            "y": 99,
            "color": "#f1c40f"
        }, {
            "name": "M",
            "y": 94,
            "color": "#e74c3c"
        }, {
            "name": "J",
            "y": 101,
            "color": "#2ecc71"
        }, {
            "name": "J",
            "y": 104,
            "color": "#2ecc71"
        }, {
            "name": "A",
            "y": 100,
            "color": "#2ecc71"
        }, {
            "name": "S",
            "y": 104,
            "color": "#2ecc71"
        }, {
            "name": "O",
            "y": 94,
            "color": "#e74c3c"
        }, {
            "name": "N",
            "y": 104,
            "color": "#2ecc71"
        }, {
            "name": "D",
            "y": 91,
            "color": "#e74c3c"
        }, {
            "name": "J",
            "y": 86,
            "color": "#e74c3c"
        }, {
            "name": "F",
            "y": 96,
            "color": "#f1c40f"
        }, {
            "name": "M",
            "y": 97,
            "color": "#f1c40f"
        }, {
            "name": "A",
            "y": 89,
            "color": "#e74c3c"
        }, {
            "name": "M",
            "y": 102,
            "color": "#2ecc71"
        }]
    }]
});


// the button action
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        selectedPoints = chart.getSelectedPoints();

    if (chart.lbl) {
        chart.lbl.destroy();
    }
    chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('You selected ' + selectedPoints.length + ' points', 100, 60)
        .attr({
        padding: 10,
        r: 5,
        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        zIndex: 5
    })
        .css({
        color: 'white'
    })
        .add();
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the [API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.max) of `max` you'll see that:

> If the `endOnTick` option is true, the `max` value might be rounded up.

So a solution is to set `endOnTick: false`, as the default is `true`. The same applies to `min`.

Note that this might make your ticks (axis labels) appear at strange points, but this can be remedied with a flood of `tick...` options like `tickInterval`, `tickPositioner`, `tickPositions`, `tickAmount`...

A example addition to your code could be ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a23j4Ljd/6/)):

```
endOnTick: false,
startOnTick: false,
tickPositions: [81,105]
```

Note that there might still be some slight spacing from `maxPadding`, which is `0.05` by default. You could also set this to `0`, but then points might go up to the very edge of the plot area.